# Прозрачность ячеек таблицы при прокрутке

Tags: ios, objective-c

На экране 7 ячеек, всего в таблице может быть n-ое число ячеек, необходимо сделать так, чтобы при прокрутке изменялась прозрачность ячеек. Ячейка по центру, 4-ая, должна быть максимально яркая, допустим `0.5`, далее вниз и наверх прозрачность должна уменьшаться, первая видимая и последняя видимая ячейки, должны быть с прозрачностью `0.2`. Прозрачность должна меняться при прокрутке плавно. Как это реализовать?

Comment: интерполяция. вам надо было не спать на лекциях про интерполяцию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    NSArray *cells = [self.tableView visibleCells];

    [cells enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UITableViewCell *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        CGFloat originOnScreen = obj.frame.origin.y - self.tableView.contentOffset.y;

        obj.alpha = 0.5 - 0.3 * fabs([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2-originOnScreen+obj.frame.size.height/2)/[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    }];
}
```